# Minimoog oscillator LTSpice simulation problem

Tags: oscillator, simulation, ltspice

I am running a simulation on the Moog Minimoog Model D oscillator in LTSpice. The circuit with the models needed is attached below.

[image: Mini MOOG Oscillator]

The square wave and triangular wave generation work as expected. The problem I am having is with the capacitor C4 charging. The charging ramp does not go to 5V as per the original schematic description, but instead reaches only ~4V. The [schematic description](https://archive.org/details/synthmanual-moog-minimoog-service-notes) (section 2.3) reads:

[image: Schematic Description]

With no voltage applied on the base of the transistor Q3, 5uA is negatively charging the bottom side of capacitor C4. This ramp is buffered by the U6 and Q5 stage and presented at the comparator U5 negative input. When the ramp reaches 0V, the comparator triggers and produces a +10V pulse that turns on the JFET J1 and brings the bottom side of the capacitor back to 5V. Well, at least in theory.

I have checked the schematic many times and verified that it (including the models used) are the same as the Model D's. I have also simulated the circuit with a 5V-0V ramp at the input of the buffer U6, and this produces correct results.

If anyone has any ideas why there is a residual ~1V across the capacitor, and if there is a way to fix it, I would be grateful.

***FullOscillator.asc***

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 1664 1252
WIRE -1088 -496 -1120 -496
WIRE -1072 -496 -1088 -496
WIRE -976 -496 -1024 -496
WIRE -1232 -464 -1232 -496
WIRE -1120 -400 -1120 -496
WIRE -1120 -400 -1136 -400
WIRE -1088 -400 -1120 -400
WIRE -976 -400 -976 -496
WIRE -976 -400 -1008 -400
WIRE -960 -400 -976 -400
WIRE -1232 -352 -1232 -384
WIRE -1184 -352 -1232 -352
WIRE -960 -352 -960 -400
WIRE -880 -352 -960 -352
WIRE -768 -352 -800 -352
WIRE -1552 -320 -1632 -320
WIRE -1392 -320 -1472 -320
WIRE -1392 -304 -1392 -320
WIRE -1328 -304 -1392 -304
WIRE -1216 -304 -1264 -304
WIRE -768 -304 -768 -352
WIRE -336 -288 -336 -336
WIRE -960 -272 -960 -352
WIRE -960 -272 -1024 -272
WIRE -1632 -256 -1632 -320
WIRE -1632 -256 -1840 -256
WIRE -1216 -256 -1216 -304
WIRE -1184 -256 -1184 -352
WIRE -1184 -256 -1216 -256
WIRE -1136 -256 -1136 -400
WIRE -1136 -256 -1184 -256
WIRE -1088 -256 -1136 -256
WIRE -960 -240 -1024 -240
WIRE -560 -240 -960 -240
WIRE -448 -240 -480 -240
WIRE -1392 -192 -1392 -304
WIRE -1328 -192 -1392 -192
WIRE -1216 -192 -1216 -256
WIRE -1216 -192 -1264 -192
WIRE -1632 -176 -1632 -256
WIRE -1456 -176 -1632 -176
WIRE -448 -176 -448 -240
WIRE -336 -176 -336 -208
WIRE -336 -176 -448 -176
WIRE 288 -176 -336 -176
WIRE 512 -176 512 -224
WIRE -1456 -160 -1456 -176
WIRE -1632 -144 -1632 -176
WIRE -1392 -128 -1392 -192
WIRE -1392 -128 -1408 -128
WIRE -560 -128 -608 -128
WIRE -448 -128 -448 -176
WIRE -448 -128 -480 -128
WIRE -608 -80 -608 -128
WIRE -752 -64 -752 -96
WIRE 512 -64 512 -96
WIRE 688 -64 512 -64
WIRE -1632 -32 -1632 -80
WIRE -1456 -32 -1456 -64
WIRE -1456 -32 -1632 -32
WIRE 512 -32 512 -64
WIRE -560 -16 -608 -16
WIRE -448 -16 -448 -128
WIRE -448 -16 -480 -16
WIRE -416 -16 -448 -16
WIRE -304 -16 -336 -16
WIRE -272 -16 -304 -16
WIRE -160 -16 -192 -16
WIRE 112 -16 16 -16
WIRE -1632 0 -1632 -32
WIRE -1312 0 -1376 0
WIRE -1200 16 -1248 16
WIRE 16 16 16 -16
WIRE -1312 32 -1456 32
WIRE -752 32 -752 16
WIRE -752 32 -800 32
WIRE -688 32 -752 32
WIRE -1104 48 -1104 -32
WIRE -800 48 -800 32
WIRE 112 48 112 -16
WIRE -1200 96 -1200 16
WIRE -1168 96 -1200 96
WIRE -864 96 -1168 96
WIRE -304 96 -304 -16
WIRE -272 96 -304 96
WIRE -1632 112 -1632 80
WIRE -1456 112 -1456 32
WIRE -1456 112 -1632 112
WIRE -160 112 -160 -16
WIRE -160 112 -208 112
WIRE -112 112 -160 112
WIRE 16 112 16 96
WIRE 16 112 -32 112
WIRE 288 112 16 112
WIRE 512 112 512 48
WIRE -688 128 -688 32
WIRE -656 128 -688 128
WIRE -544 128 -576 128
WIRE -528 128 -544 128
WIRE -304 128 -352 128
WIRE -272 128 -304 128
WIRE -800 176 -800 144
WIRE 912 176 912 96
WIRE 1024 176 1024 96
WIRE 1136 176 1136 96
WIRE -1376 192 -1376 0
WIRE -1104 192 -1104 144
WIRE -1104 192 -1376 192
WIRE -960 192 -960 -240
WIRE -960 192 -1104 192
WIRE -464 192 -464 128
WIRE 912 192 912 176
WIRE -416 208 -416 128
WIRE -304 256 -304 128
WIRE -272 256 -304 256
WIRE 288 256 -192 256
WIRE -1376 272 -1536 272
WIRE -1296 272 -1376 272
WIRE 672 272 512 272
WIRE -800 288 -800 256
WIRE -304 288 -304 256
WIRE -1376 304 -1376 272
WIRE 672 304 672 272
WIRE -544 320 -544 128
WIRE -496 320 -544 320
WIRE -1632 336 -1632 112
WIRE -1536 336 -1536 272
WIRE -384 336 -432 336
WIRE -496 352 -544 352
WIRE -1696 384 -1840 384
WIRE -1440 384 -1472 384
WIRE -304 384 -304 368
WIRE 512 384 512 352
WIRE -384 416 -384 336
WIRE 288 416 -384 416
WIRE 512 416 512 384
WIRE -1584 432 -1632 432
WIRE -1536 432 -1584 432
WIRE -1376 448 -1376 384
WIRE -1440 464 -1440 384
WIRE -1840 480 -1840 384
WIRE -544 480 -544 352
WIRE -512 480 -544 480
WIRE -384 480 -384 416
WIRE -384 480 -432 480
WIRE -1584 496 -1584 432
WIRE -544 512 -544 480
WIRE -1472 544 -1504 544
WIRE -1376 544 -1408 544
WIRE -1296 544 -1296 272
WIRE 512 560 512 496
WIRE -1840 656 -1840 560
WIRE -1296 656 -1296 544
WIRE -1296 656 -1392 656
WIRE -1584 672 -1584 576
WIRE -1552 672 -1584 672
WIRE -1504 672 -1504 544
WIRE -1504 672 -1552 672
WIRE -1456 672 -1504 672
WIRE 512 672 512 640
WIRE -1296 688 -1392 688
WIRE -1552 704 -1552 672
WIRE -1296 752 -1296 688
WIRE -1552 800 -1552 768
FLAG 1024 176 0
FLAG 1024 16 +10V
FLAG 1136 16 -10V
FLAG 912 16 +5V
FLAG 912 176 0
FLAG 1136 176 0
FLAG -608 -80 0
FLAG -608 -16 -10V
FLAG 288 112 SQU
FLAG 112 48 0
FLAG -240 144 +10V
FLAG -240 80 -10V
FLAG -752 -96 +5V
FLAG -800 288 0
FLAG 672 304 0
FLAG 512 672 -10V
FLAG -304 384 0
FLAG 288 256 DUTY
FLAG -464 192 0
FLAG 288 416 TRI
FLAG -464 368 +10V
FLAG -544 592 +10V
FLAG -464 304 -10V
FLAG 512 -224 TRI
FLAG 512 112 SAW
FLAG 688 -64 BENT
FLAG 512 384 DUTY
FLAG -336 -336 +10V
FLAG 288 -176 SAW
FLAG -416 208 0
FLAG -768 -304 0
FLAG -1280 -16 +10V
FLAG -1056 -224 +10V
FLAG -1280 48 -10V
FLAG -1056 -288 -10V
FLAG -1232 -496 +10V
FLAG -1840 656 0
FLAG -1376 448 +10V
FLAG -1440 464 0
FLAG -1296 752 0
FLAG -1552 800 0
FLAG -1104 -32 +10V
FLAG -1840 -256 +5V
FLAG -1424 640 +10V
FLAG -1424 704 -10V
SYMBOL voltage 912 0 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 5
SYMBOL voltage 1024 0 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 10
SYMBOL voltage 1136 0 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMATTR Value -10
SYMBOL res -464 -32 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 4.02K
SYMBOL res -464 -144 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 5.6K
SYMBOL Opamps\\UniversalOpamp2 -464 336 M180
SYMATTR InstName U1
SYMBOL res -320 -32 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 1K
SYMBOL res -176 -32 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 2.2Meg
SYMBOL res -16 96 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value 5.1K
SYMBOL res 0 0 R0
SYMATTR InstName R6
SYMATTR Value 2.7K
SYMBOL npn2 -864 48 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q1
SYMATTR Value 2N3904
SYMBOL res -816 160 R0
SYMATTR InstName R7
SYMATTR Value 10K
SYMBOL res -768 -80 R0
SYMATTR InstName R8
SYMATTR Value 10K
SYMBOL res -560 496 R0
SYMATTR InstName R9
SYMATTR Value 8.25K
SYMBOL res -416 464 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R10
SYMATTR Value 4.99K
SYMBOL res -560 112 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R11
SYMATTR Value 10K
SYMBOL res 528 368 R180
WINDOW 0 36 76 Left 2
WINDOW 3 36 40 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName R12
SYMATTR Value 1.5K
SYMBOL res 528 512 R180
WINDOW 0 36 76 Left 2
WINDOW 3 36 40 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName R13
SYMATTR Value 1K
SYMBOL res 528 656 R180
WINDOW 0 36 76 Left 2
WINDOW 3 36 40 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName R14
SYMATTR Value 7.5K
SYMBOL res -320 272 R0
SYMATTR InstName R15
SYMATTR Value 100K
SYMBOL res -176 240 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R16
SYMATTR Value 100K
SYMBOL cap -352 112 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 0.01µ
SYMATTR SpiceLine V=4 Irms=162m Rser=0.395426 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0402C103K7PAC" type="X5R"
SYMBOL Opamps\\opamp2 -240 176 M180
SYMATTR InstName U2
SYMATTR Value LM393A
SYMBOL res 496 -192 R0
SYMATTR InstName R17
SYMATTR Value 10K
SYMBOL res 496 -48 R0
SYMATTR InstName R18
SYMATTR Value 47K
SYMBOL res -464 -256 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R19
SYMATTR Value 1K
SYMBOL res -352 -304 R0
SYMATTR InstName R20
SYMATTR Value 220K
SYMBOL cap -464 112 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 500p
SYMBOL res -1568 -304 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName R21
SYMATTR Value 100K
SYMATTR SpiceLine tol=1 pwr=0.1
SYMBOL diode -1328 -288 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMATTR Value 1N4148
SYMBOL res -1248 -480 R0
SYMATTR InstName R22
SYMATTR Value 2K
SYMATTR SpiceLine tol=1 pwr=0.1
SYMBOL npn -1696 336 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q3
SYMBOL voltage -1840 464 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V8
SYMATTR Value 0mV
SYMBOL npn -1472 336 M0
SYMATTR InstName Q4
SYMBOL res -1600 480 R0
SYMATTR InstName R23
SYMATTR Value 100K
SYMBOL res -1392 288 R0
SYMATTR InstName R24
SYMATTR Value 2Meg
SYMBOL res -1280 528 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R25
SYMATTR Value 1K
SYMATTR SpiceLine tol=1 pwr=0.1
SYMBOL cap -1408 528 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName C3
SYMATTR Value 0.001µ
SYMATTR SpiceLine V=6.3 Irms=25.7m Rser=3.62516 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0402C102K9RAC" type="X7R"
SYMBOL diode -1568 704 R0
SYMATTR InstName D2
SYMATTR Value 1N4148
SYMBOL Opamps\\opamp2 -1056 -192 R180
SYMATTR InstName U5
SYMATTR Value LM393A
SYMBOL cap -1616 -80 R180
WINDOW 0 24 57 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 8 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName C4
SYMATTR Value 0.001µ
SYMATTR Description Polarized Capacitor
SYMATTR Type polcap
SYMATTR SpiceLine V=6.3 Irms=25.7m Rser=3.62516 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0402C102K9RAC" type="X7R"
SYMBOL njf -1408 -64 R180
SYMATTR InstName J1
SYMATTR Value J112
SYMBOL res -992 -416 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R27
SYMATTR Value 1Meg
SYMBOL res -784 -368 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R28
SYMATTR Value 100
SYMBOL cap -1328 -176 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName C5
SYMATTR Value 100p
SYMATTR Description Polarized Capacitor
SYMATTR Type polcap
SYMATTR SpiceLine V=25 Irms=0 Rser=0 Lser=0 mfg="Murata" pn="GRM0335C1E101JA01" type="C0G"
SYMBOL cap -1024 -512 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName C6
SYMATTR Value 18p
SYMATTR Description Polarized Capacitor
SYMATTR Type polcap
SYMATTR SpiceLine V=25 Irms=0 Rser=0 Lser=0 mfg="Murata" pn="GCM0335C1E180JA16" type="C0G"
SYMBOL npn -1168 48 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q5
SYMATTR Value 2N3904
SYMBOL Opamps\\opamp2 -1280 -48 R0
SYMATTR InstName U6
SYMATTR Value TL081
SYMBOL Opamps\\opamp2 -1424 608 M0
SYMATTR InstName U4
SYMATTR Value TL081
SYMBOL res -1648 -16 R0
SYMATTR InstName R26
SYMATTR Value 5K
TEXT 904 232 Left 2 !.tran 0 10ms 0 0.5ms startup
TEXT 904 288 Left 2 !.include TL081.301
TEXT 904 336 Left 2 !.include LM393A.5_1
TEXT 904 392 Left 2 ;.wave "C:\\Users\\Boris\\Desktop\\Sawtooth.wav" 16 44.1k V(saw)\n.wave "C:\\Users\\Boris\\Desktop\\Square.wav" 16 44.1k V(squ)\n.wave "C:\\Users\\Boris\\Desktop\\Bent.wav" 16 44.1k V(bent)
TEXT 912 528 Left 2 !.options cshunt = 1e-13
TEXT 904 480 Left 2 ;.wave "C:\\Users\\Boris\\Desktop\\Triangle.wav" 16 44.1k V(tri)
```

***LM393A.5_1***

```
* LM393A VOLTAGE COMPARATOR "MACROMODEL" SUBCIRCUIT
* CREATED USING PARTS VERSION 4.03 ON 03/07/90 AT 14:17
* REV (N/A)
* CONNECTIONS:   NON-INVERTING INPUT
*                | INVERTING INPUT
*                | | POSITIVE POWER SUPPLY
*                | | | NEGATIVE POWER SUPPLY
*                | | | | OPEN COLLECTOR OUTPUT
*                | | | | |
.SUBCKT LM393A   1 2 3 4 5
*
  F1    9  3 V1 1
  IEE   3  7 DC 100.0E-6
  VI1  21  1 DC .75
  VI2  22  2 DC .75
  Q1    9 21  7 QIN
  Q2    8 22  7 QIN
  Q3    9  8  4 QMO
  Q4    8  8  4 QMI
.MODEL QIN PNP(IS=800.0E-18 BF=2.000E3)
.MODEL QMI NPN(IS=800.0E-18 BF=1002)
.MODEL QMO NPN(IS=800.0E-18 BF=1000 CJC=1E-15 TR=807.4E-9)
  E1   10  4  9  4  1
  V1   10 11 DC 0
  Q5    5 11  4 QOC
.MODEL QOC NPN(IS=800.0E-18 BF=20.29E3 CJC=1E-15 TF=942.6E-12 TR=543.8E-9)
  DP    4  3 DX
  RP 3  4 46.3E3
.MODEL DX  D(IS=800.0E-18)
*
.ENDS
```

***TL081.301***

```
* TL081 OPERATIONAL AMPLIFIER "MACROMODEL" SUBCIRCUIT
* CREATED USING PARTS RELEASE 4.01 ON 06/16/89 AT 13:08
* (REV N/A)      SUPPLY VOLTAGE: +/-15V
* CONNECTIONS:   NON-INVERTING INPUT
*                | INVERTING INPUT
*                | | POSITIVE POWER SUPPLY
*                | | | NEGATIVE POWER SUPPLY
*                | | | | OUTPUT
*                | | | | |
.SUBCKT TL081    1 2 3 4 5
*
  C1   11 12 3.498E-12
  C2    6  7 15.00E-12
  DC    5 53 DX
  DE   54  5 DX
  DLP  90 91 DX
  DLN  92 90 DX
  DP    4  3 DX
  EGND 99  0 POLY(2) (3,0) (4,0) 0 .5 .5
  FB    7 99 POLY(5) VB VC VE VLP VLN 0 4.715E6 -5E6 5E6 5E6 -5E6
  GA    6  0 11 12 282.8E-6
  GCM   0  6 10 99 8.942E-9
  ISS   3 10 DC 195.0E-6
  HLIM 90  0 VLIM 1K
  J1   11  2 10 JX
  J2   12  1 10 JX
  R2    6  9 100.0E3
  RD1   4 11 3.536E3
  RD2   4 12 3.536E3
  RO1   8  5 150
  RO2   7 99 150
  RP    3  4 2.143E3
  RSS  10 99 1.026E6
  VB    9  0 DC 0
  VC    3 53 DC 2.200
  VE   54  4 DC 2.200
  VLIM  7  8 DC 0
  VLP  91  0 DC 25
  VLN   0 92 DC 25
.MODEL DX D(IS=800.0E-18)
.MODEL JX PJF(IS=15.00E-12 BETA=270.1E-6 VTO=-1)
.ENDS
```

Answer (score 2):

After looking over the schematic there is one thing that I could see that could be affecting the simulation, you don't have real NPN's, but ideal spice NPN's. Put in the real NPN's and that might fix your problem. If it doesn't then I'll simulate the circuit and see if there is another problem.

Answer (score 1):

Which original schematic description?  According to [FantasyJackPalance](http://www.fantasyjackpalance.com/fjp/sound/synth/synthdata/16-moog-minimoog.html#3a), the swing should be `+3v to 0v`:

[image: MOOG Minimoog D]

I was able to force a ~5v swing by changing C4 from X7R to C0G (lower parasitics) and the J112 to a J108 (lower beta) but this is technically a hack.

Comment: Hm, I haven't noticed that on the schematic. I have some difficulty to believe that the swing should be +3V, but then at +5V at the input of the comparator as the TL081 and 2N3904 only act a buffer. I've managed to track down the original explanations in the Minimoog manual:

https://imgur.com/a/PLm5A5E

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if someone has a real board they could 'scope to give us actual values.